# How do I make the replacement of the Propertymetadata class with its new replacement in NativeScript 3.0?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am studying how to create plugins, however the plugin I chose is not compatible with version 3.0 of NativeScript, on that I am trying to migrate it to this new version.

At the moment I'm having a hard time finding which class I should use to replace it, how to do it.

NativeScript's documentation at this point is very precarious and leaves much to be desired, or I'm not finding the right place to study.

How do I make the replacement of the Propertymetadata class with its new replacement in NativeScript 3.0?

And what is the right class for such a replacement?

**Updating**:

I re-read and extended the reading for the following articles, but none of them delves into the functionalities and proper use of such classes and their dependencies and dependents.

- https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin
- http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding
- http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/properties
- github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/wiki/…

Comment: There's a breaking change document on the repo that covers plugins in depth. On phone or I'd find it.

Comment: this: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/wiki/Migrating-Plugins-to-NativeScript-3.0 ?

Comment: Looks like the doc I was referencing